# Pokemon log in situation

Tags: pokemon-go

My son used my wife's .msn email to set up his account. It appears to be associated with the Google log in. No big deal....
My wife is trying to install Pokemon go on her phone and ALSO wants to log in using the .msn email (so she can help build his profile now and then)

The issue is, her phone has a Gmail account, and Pokemon go is trying to use it when I click on the Google button.

How do I get it to use the .msn email instead

Comment: As innocuous as this is, having your wife and son play on the same account would likely result in a ban as it violates Niantic's one-account-one-human policy.